# How to use Gatsby code snippet with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'd like to use a GraphQL code snippet in an '.mdx' file:

````
---
title: Releasing A GitHub Action
date: "2021-03-22T12:35:16"
slug: /blog/releasing-a-github-action
description: "After using other people's GitHub Actions, I thought I'd give one a shot."
---


this is text in the .mdx file

/```graphql
mutation UpdateAllEnvironmentVariablesForSite(
  $id: UUID!
  $buildEnvironmentVariables: [TagInput!]!
  $previewEnvironmentVariables: [TagInput!]!
) {
  updateBuildEnvironmentVariablesForSite: updateEnvironmentVariablesForSite(
    id: $id
    environmentVariables: $buildEnvironmentVariables
    runnerType: BUILDS
  ) {
    success
    message
  }
  updatePreviewEnvironmentVariablesForSite: updateEnvironmentVariablesForSite(
    id: $id
    environmentVariables: $previewEnvironmentVariables
    runnerType: PREVIEW
  ) {
    success
    message
  }
}
/```
Continuing to write .mdx
````

When I develop this, it looks fine. When I build it in Gatsby Cloud, I get the error

> Encountered unknown language 'graphql'. If 'graphql' is an alias for a supported language, use the 'languageAliases' plugin option to map it to the canonical language name.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Can you provide the top part of the MDX?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [MDX+Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/mdx/writing-pages/#graphql-queries):

> Note: For now, this only works [if the `.mdx` file exporting the query is
> placed in `src/pages`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/mdx/writing-pages/#:%7E:text=if%20the%20.mdx%20file%20exporting%20the%20query%20is%20placed%20in%20src/pages). Exporting GraphQL queries from `.mdx` files that
> are used for programmatic page creation in `gatsby-node.js` via
> `actions.createPage` [is not currently supported](https://github.com/ChristopherBiscardi/gatsby-mdx/issues/187#issuecomment-489005677).

A sample working query in a `.mdx` file looks like:

```
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
# My Awesome Page
Here's a paragraph, followed by a paragraph with data!
<p>{props.data.site.siteMetadata.description}</p>
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        description
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

In your case, I guess that your snippet won't work even outside the `.mdx` file in a `gatsby build` because you are not exporting the query or using a page-query approach. Try adapting your GraphQL query to the "common" way to see how it behaves.

Comment: I ended up removing the 'graphql' from the snippet. It's a bummer that the pages created programmatically aren't supported. Any idea if there's a work-around?